# String.Split doesn't appear to be using overloads correctly

Tags: c#, winforms

Simple issue of whenever I ported over a console app class into a Windows Form class, the only thing that bricked was using String.Split to separate into a specified number of sub strings. Not sure why this is the case as I can peek the overloads and can confirm that the char[], int overload is there. Here's a picture.

[image: error code and example line throwing error]

Comment: Are you sure that `line.Split(',', 3)` ever worked? I can't find any documentation which says that that overload has ever existed

Comment: There is no overload that takes a `char` and `int`.  Did you mean to use the one that takes a `char[]`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_?

Comment: @canton7 possibly they had an extension method in the old code that took it like that and then created an array and used the overload that has an array and an integer

Comment: it's strange that it worked with just a singular character in the console app prior code, I simply took it for granted that the char array could simply be a one element array with no brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're trying to use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_) version of the `String.Split` method, your first argument needs to be an array.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) is a list of overloads that are supported.
Using `String.Split(',')` works since [that overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___) specifies that the `separator` argument is a `params` argument.

However, when you want to use the `Split(char[], int)` overload, the first argument is not specified as a params argument, which means you have to use that method like this:

```
var sections = line.Split(new[] {','}, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no overload that takes a single character. You want the one that takes an array:

```
string[] parts = line.Split(new char[]{','}, 3)
```

Comment: oh shoot I don't know why it worked in the console app I had before then. Thanks!

Comment: @Sauce If you can open the old code, try right clicking on the method call where you are using it and clicking on "Go to Definition"